# wkhtmltopdf - margin top different from page to page - how?

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

How do I set a different `margin` on each page?

At the moment I can set a global `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

But for example, on my cover page, and my last page I don't want a `margin`.

How can i do that?

Comment: I don't _think_ you can. I've been trying to do the same. I've tried using JS to set the CSS but its ignored. I'll monitor this question with anticipation but I've not found a method yet. I imagine you will need to create 3 PDFs and join them together.

Comment: Thx for your info Chris. I'll await. Untill then, perhaps I will merge the PDFs.